# How to generate .pkpass from Windows computer?

Tags: ios, passbook, passkit

Is it possible to create `.pkpass file` from Windows computer?

I have `KeyStore` and `Certificate` files obtained from Mac and Provisioning portal respectively. i.e, Certificates.p12, MembershipCard.cer

I have used `passkit4j` which creates `.pkpass file` but the same can't be opened in iPhone. In iPhone mail client, the attachment looks like (null)

Can anyone please let me know what I'm missing here. It would be a great help if Step-by-step tutorial provided for `passkit4j`.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, the looks very much like a problem with your certificates.  Your .p12 file must contain the private key used to create the CSR you uploaded to the provisioning portal and the Pass Type ID Certificate.  You also need to include the [WWDR certificate](http://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer).  I am not sure what your MembershipCard.cer is or why you have included it.

If you have access to a Mac, then turning on additional Passbook logging and monitoring the device logs in Xcode as you install the pass may provide some insight as to why your pass is not loading.

If you do not have access to a Mac, then if you can post a link to a .pkpass bundle that is not loading then we can take a quick look at it for you.